# Some entries in H5 file gets corrupt when transferred using SFTP

Tags: sftp, hdf5, h5py

I have multiple, large H5 files in the server which I copy to my local using SFTP. I use the following syntax `get -r <path_to_file>/<file.h5>`.

When I attempt to read certain entries, say,

```
h5_obj = h5py.File(<file.h5>, 'r')
data = h5_obj['Images'][407, ...]
```

It returns the following error message

> OSError: Can't read data (inflate() failed)

A quick search reveals that this message pertains to a corrupt file. Note that the exact same data sample can be read successfully on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you compared file sizes between the server and local copy? They should be nearly identical. If not, delete the local copy and try again. Note: HDF5 is a binary file. Be sure you use appropriate sftp flags to copy as binary.

If they are similar, it's possible the file has external links. These are used to point to data in other files. There are some HDF5 utilities you run to check the file schema and contents. They are:

- **ptdump**: a utility included in the PyTables package. It is a command line tool that interrogates a HDF file.
- **h5dump**: a utility from The HDF Group. It is another command line tool to interrogate a HDF file. (requires download and install of HDF5).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll follow your recommendations and report what I find.